# zip list too many items to unpack

Tags: python, for-loop, zip, mysql-python

i have a zipped list with 13 lists. I would like to insert the items into a mysql database. here is my code:

```
zipped_list=zip(list1,list2...list13)
for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m in zipped_list:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO QB_global_sentiment(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %("date","US_pos","US_neg","US_neu","UK_pos","UK_neg","UK_neu","CA_pos","CA_neg","CA_neu","AU_pos","AU_neg","AU_neu",str(m), str(a),str(b),str(c),str(d),str(e),str(f),str(g),str(h),str(i),str(j),str(k),str(l)))
```

This is my error:

```
    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m in zipped_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I agree there is too many items and its really long..is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see an example of `zipped_list` on which this fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have a list of 13 lists, and want parallel iteration. To do this, you could use `zip()`, as illustrated by the simple example below:

```
In [8]: l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

In [9]: for a, b in zip(*l):
   ...:     print a, b
   ...:     
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Answer (score 2):

> I agree there is too many items and its really long.

The message doesn't mean there are "too many" in the sense of "more than x number is a bad idea".  It means "too many" in the sense of the number of zipped elements doesn't match the number of variables.

FWIW, you don't need to unpack into separate variables (the *execute()* method will accept a tuple or list), nor do you need to have a for-loop (the *executemany()* method will do that for you).  Also, the *execute()* methods will do the substitutions with several benefits: helping avoid sQL injection attacks, improving speed, and improving clarity.

Try something along these lines:

```
cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO QB_global_sentiment(date, US_pos, US_neg, US_neu, UK_pos, UK_neg, UK_neu, CA_pos, CA_neg, CA_neu, AU_pos, AU_neg , AU_neu)
                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', combined_data)
```

Comment: what does the variable combined_data comprise of? is it a zipped list of my 13 lists? `combined_data=zip(list1,list2...list13)`?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions**

1. If the values are going to change at runtime, you might want to hardcode them, instead of filling them.
2. It is always better to fix the problem with the number of items in the items returned in the iteration.

If I were you, I would have done it similar to this

```
for row in zipped_list:
    print ("...{} {} {} {}".format(*row[:4])
```

This takes the list/tuple from the `zipped_list` and it uses only the number of columns you want to actually fill.

**Example:**

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
for a in data:
    print("{} {}".format(*a[:2]))
```

**Output**

```
1 2
4 5
```